# SQL function to determine the most accurate result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table like this...

```
create table #words (
id int identity,
word varchar(1024)
)

insert into #words (word) values ('dock')
insert into #words (word) values ('dockable')
```

and i do a LIKE query

```
select id, word from #words where word like '%dock%'
```

Is there a way to tell which result would be the most accurate?

Comment: This depends on what you consider accurate, rushonerok.  Would 'docker' be more accurate than 'dockable' since it's the smaller of the two, for example?

Comment: As described by OMG Ponies and Remus, SQL FTS is the right solution for your problem. As these algorithms, takes into account - Inflectional forms of a specific word (generation term)

A word or phrase close to another word or phrase (proximity term)

Synonymous forms of a specific word (thesaurus)

Words or phrases using weighted values (weighted term)

For more info read - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For complex multi-word criteria you should use Full Text Search and [`CONTAINSTABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx). The output of this table function contains a `RANK` column:

> The table produced by `CONTAINSTABLE`
>   includes a column named `RANK`. The `RANK`
>   column is a value (from 0 through
>   1000) for each row indicating how well
>   a row matched the selection criteria.
>   This rank value is typically used in
>   one of these ways in the `SELECT`
>   statement:
>
> - In the `ORDER BY` clause to return the highest-ranking rows as the first rows
>     in the table.
> - In the select list to see the rank value assigned to each row.

For simple single word criteria you should implement a [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) function in SQL CLR and use that to find the most similar best match words (or use the one from Ken Redler's linked project).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using similarity metrics to get a distance score for each result as compared to the search string. [`SOUNDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) and the like give you some primitive options, but there are much more sophisticated alternatives, depending on your requirement. The [SimMetrics library of functions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) allows you to compare strings by Hamming distance, Levenshtein distance, etc. Here's a [thorough article](http://anastasiosyal.com/archive/2009/01/11/18.aspx) describing the installation and usage of the library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SOUNDEX and DIFFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259235%28SQL.80%29.aspx) T-SQL functions to compare words, but you may still need a way to determine which is "most accurate".

For example, run the following queries:

```
SELECT DIFFERENCE('dock','dock');
SELECT DIFFERENCE('dock','dockable');
```

Difference of 'dock' and 'dock' is 4, which is the best result; 'dock' and 'docakble' is a 2, which is a higher difference.

Comment: I hadn't realised T-SQL supported SOUNDEX.  Yuck.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using Full Text Searching (FTS) - [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) is more precise than [FREETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx)

### CONTAINS

```
WHERE CONTAINS(word, 'dock')
```

### FREETEXT

```
WHERE FREETEXT (word, 'dock')
```

Indexed, these will be faster than LIKE and FTS includes a score value based on an algorithm to rank matching.  You'll have to test & see if the results fit your needs.